# jQuery UI sortable touch duration

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, touch, jquery-ui-sortable, threshold

I'm developing a comparison site where you're able to sort items horizontally using jQuery UI's sortable function. All items are within a container which can be scrolled horizontally or vertically.
It works fine on desktop and I'm trying to make it work on tablets.

[image: Comparison]

I could already make the sortable functionality work on tablets by the following: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDRuL/)

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", module.bindTouchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", module.bindTouchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchend", module.bindTouchHandler, true);
document.addEventListener("touchcancel", module.bindTouchHandler, true); 

module.bindTouchHandler = function(event){
    var touch = event.changedTouches[0];

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent({
        touchstart: "mousedown",
        touchmove: "mousemove",
        touchend: "mouseup"
    }[event.type], true, true, window, 1,
                                  touch.screenX, touch.screenY,
                                  touch.clientX, touch.clientY, false,
                                  false, false, false, 0, null);

    touch.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

The problem is that the different touch events prevent now the possibility to scroll horizontally/vertically. I'd like to have a delay on this. Like only start sorting/dragging the element if the user's touching it for 2 seconds.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Have you ever developed some solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't comment directly to your problem, I recently faced a similar issue of using jQuery UI on touch devices. While official touch support for jQuery is coming down the line in ([expected to show in version 1.14](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138038/Roadmap)), furf has created an elegant hack that allows touch to work with jQuery UI with zero effort. Check it out here: http://touchpunch.furf.com/